# IE5 and IE6 Line Break doesn't work

Tags: css, internet-explorer, whitespace

i have a question about line Breaks on IE5 and IE6
*(i've tested on IE Emulator http://i58.tinypic.com/2whfo5s.png)* 
ie5 and IE6 supports normally "white-space:normal", 
but in my example doesn't work.

(It works already on Firefox and Chrome.)

HTML Code :

```
<div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 50%;">

        <div style="width: 100%;" id="element1">
            <input
                value="a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p r s t u y z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p r s t u y z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p r s t u y z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p r s t u y z"
                type="button">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end of line 7  -->


    <!-- line 8  -->
    <div style="float: left; width: 50%;">

        <div style="width: 100%; margin-left: 1px;" id="element2">
            <input
                value="a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p r s t u y z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p r s t u y z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p r s t u y z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p r s t u y z"
                type="button">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end of line 8  -->
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#element1 input,
#element2 input{
    white-space: normal;
    height: 64px !important;
    width:100%;
    border: medium none !important;
    background-color: #0288D1 !important;
    color: #FFF !important;
    padding: 3px 0px 0px 4px !important;
}
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/aldimeola1122/qu2moj33/

Can you help me? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any reason why you try to optimize site for dead IE5?

Comment: yes, there is reason, because we must use handheld devices.

Comment: Which handheld devices have IE5 (and no newer browsers)??

Comment: for an example intermec ck71 based on ie6, http://www.intermec.de/products/cmptrck71a/downloads.aspx

Comment: Hahaha asked for what uses ie5 you give an example of something that uses ie6: "Locked-down data collection browser based on the Internet Explorer 6 engine"

Comment: my code also doesn't work on ie6